# Bagger or leaf blower?

Tags: lawn

I am surrounded by woods and have been bagging leaves and dumping in the surrounding woods. I also have used baggers to cut unwanted grass if it looks as if it's going to seed.I recently purchased a new lawn tractor and must either purchase a bagger or a powerful leaf blower. The leaves are very thick. The leaf blower would probably be faster, but the bagger offers, if I am correct about the value of bagging unwanted grass, an additional advantage. Can anyone send me an opinion. It would be greatly appreciated. Having both would be ideal but expensive.
Thanks
Mark A.

Answer (score 5):

MULCH those leaves!  I lived in a lot that had so many leaves that I had to mow the lawn in four directions to shred the leaves every weekend for a month, every year.  It is free food for your lawn.  As long as 50% of the grass blades can see the light, it will be fine.

The first year I did this, I was a little reluctant because I had so many leaves covering the ground.  You wouldn't believe what it looked like pre-winter.  Every nook and cranny of the grass bed was filled with shredded leaf debris.  I was scared it would smother the lawn.  Oh no - it turned into compost and my lawn loved me for it.  It also left a wonderful smell in the air.

Answer (score 1):

You are best staying with a VACUUM or a bagger.  Dumping chopped up leaves and grass clippings in the natural area is a good thing.  Always keep your piles thin.  A leaf blower is best as a backpack gas blower all by itself.  I couldn't live without my backpack blower. Get a separate gas powered backpack blower.  You will never regret the expenditure!